# "answered X hours ago by Y" link should go to Y's answer rather than to the top of the question

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Each site's home presents a list of recently active questions.  For those items that are marked "answered X hours ago by Y", the link goes to the top of the question.

When I click on the link, especially for old questions, it is almost always in order to see the new answer, and I then have to scroll down and search for it.  If there are a lot of answers, the new one is usually near, but not at, the end.

It would be a lot more convenient if the link were to the new answer itself.

---

EDIT: I've been clicking on the item's title.  Thanks to MEE's comment, I now know that the "answered ..." text is also clickable, and does what I wanted:  [image: Example]

My (now minor) complaint is that the "answered" text isn't obviously clickable.  The title and person are blue, but the "answer" doesn't turn blue until I hover over it.

Comment: It does go to the answer for me.  Can you point to a specific example?  What browser are you using, and do you have any userscripts?

Comment: In addition to what @Monica said: you should also be able to go to the latest activity on the post by clicking the "active: 3 mins ago" link in the right sidebar (only the timestamp is a link)